# How to iterate through userform textboxes in a VBA sub-routine

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform, subroutine

In a userform, I want the user to input Time in textboxes named 'UFtime1', 'UFtime2', 'UFtime3' and so on. I have written code that makes the textbox only accept inputs in a certain format, and I want to apply this code to every textbox. I want to use a loop to target the desired textbox, but I can't figure out how to change the name of the textbox based on how many times the loop has iterated.

I have written a subroutine to do this once.

```
Private Sub UFtime1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    
    Dim dTime As String
    On Error Resume Next
    dTime = Me.UFtime1.Value
    UFtime1.Text = Format(dTime, "hh:mmAM/PM")
    If IsDate(UFtime1) Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    UFtime1 = Null
    
End Sub
```

So here, I want to add a loop which essentially changes the 1 in every UFtime**1** to a 2, then a 3, and so on with each iteration of the loop

Comment: Are you using a UserForm with a control called _UFTime1_ to set the text in a text box also called _UFTime1_? You code only appears to set the set text in the userform control. Please disambiguate.

Comment: Add a counter to increase the number of the `UFTime_n`